# Start New Activity with Sending Broadcast in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I want to Start `DashBoardActivity` after a successful attempt on `LoginActivity`. I also want to Broadcast UserToken after logged in. But either I can `startActivity()` or `sendBroadcast().` If I used the following code in `LoginActivity.kt` then

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener {
    if(loginSuccess){
         sendBroadcast(Intent("TEST"))
         startActivity(Intent(this, DashboardActivity::class.java))
         finish()
    }
}
```

`Dashboard Activity` will open, but Broadcast `onReceive()` does not work. Please help me to properly do this task.

DashBoardActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)

        registerReceiver(userDataChangeReceiver,
            IntentFilter("TEST"))
    }

    private val userDataChangeReceiver = object: BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            println("succeess!")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using a broadcast receiver? You can start the activity putting the token inside the intent. Something like: Intent intent = new Intent(context, DashboardActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(KEY, <your value here>);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: My focus is on Broadcast... so

Comment: Ok but you shouldn't use Broadcast Receivers to provide tokens across your app. Anyways, you should post your DashboardActivity code to check if the receiver is registered

Comment: I've updated the Post

Comment: problem is that you are sending the broadcast before the receiver is registered. You're registering the receiver in the activity, but you're sending the broadcast when the activity isn't started yet

Comment: Then, Please suggest me, what would be the best way?...

Comment: If you still want to use broadcast receiver, use sendBroadcast after startActivity(Intent(this, DashboardActivity::class.java)), but I'm not 100% sure that it will work, otherwise you can put an extra into your intent, but let me know if it's the case

Comment: Still not worked!... same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)

  val userDataChangeReceiver = object: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        println("succeess!")
    }
 }

    registerReceiver(userDataChangeReceiver,
        IntentFilter("TEST"))
 }
}
```

Comment: ```DashboardActivity``` started, but ```onReceive()``` method not worked!